# Trying to pass a number to use in a nth-child expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to pass a value to be used inside of that function.

```
addRemoveUnderline(5);

function addRemoveUnderline(navIndexNumber){
   console.log(navIndexNumber + " is index number");
   // remove selected class to main menu
   $('header a div').removeClass( "nav-selected");
   // add selected class to main menu
   $('header li:nth-child(navIndexNumber) div').addClass("nav-selected");
}
```

The console log is giving me the correct value, but I keep getting this error message: unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Answer (score 0):

```
$('header li:nth-child('+navIndexNumber+') div').addClass("nav-selected");
```

try this

using this

```
$('header li:nth-child(navIndexNumber) div').addClass("nav-selected");
```

by this variable value will not work and take it as string, by concatenation this will get value of variable.

Comment: Improve this answer further by explaining to the OP, and anyone else whom may benefit from this answer, *why* the intended result was not being achieved with the given syntax.

Comment: "*[Try] this*" - why? What does it do? How does it work? Why does it work? Is this just a guess or is this the answer?